# Ruby on Rails Vacuum Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, rubygems

I am new to Ruby on Rails and I am trying to access the Amazon Product API using the Vacuum Gem. Based off this code https://gist.github.com/frankie-loves-jesus/89d24dd88579c7f912f3 I am getting an error at the first line

```
request = Vacuum.new('GB')
```

telling me that I have an "Uninitialized constant AmazonAPIController::Vacuum" every example on this gem tells me to use this line of code but I can't understand how to fix the error. It seems to be as simple as putting the code into my controller and showing it.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't add the gem to your Gemfile I guess and didn't run `bundle install` afterwards. Also you should make sure to restart your Rails server after every change in your Gemfile.

If all that doesn't help, you also could try to just `gem install vacuum` and then `require 'vacuum'` in the file you are using (but I would recommend getting it to work on another way).